# Setting up impala

Tags: cloudera, hadoop2, impala

Does any one have experience in installing or building Impala from Cloudera Tarball or Git ? I have been facing issues in the prerequisites. I couldn't find any proper steps in setting up impala on centos 7.2 .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What are the steps you followed? What does the error log show?
Is the Hive metastore running?